# How can I play 'Zombies Ate My Friends' following the app store removal?

Tags: technical-issues, emulation, zombies-ate-my-friends

For the past few days, I have wanted to play the game *Zombies Ate My Friends*. The issue is, it was removed from the app store, and none of the files I have tried have worked with any emulator I have tried.

I tried unzipping a file from APKCombo and putting it into unity to build but since an APK is a finished build, it can't go back into unity fully built.

What can I do? Can I just not play it anymore?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [source](https://glumobile.helpshift.com/hc/en/23-legacy-games/faq/9951-zombies-ate-my-friends/?p=ios):

> To our loyal community,
>
> Thanks for supporting Zombies Ate My Friends. We are so lucky to have
> such passionate players in our community. Unfortunately, Zombies Ate
> My Friends will no longer be available to play after July 19, 2021.

If the game used an active server (which is likely since it is a social game), even if you rebuild the game from the decompiled code, you are still missing the server counter part. Without that, the game won't run.

And just because you did not need to select a server does not mean there wasn't one. Think of the game like a television and the server is a channel. If the channel does not exist anymore, it doesn't matter if you manage to turn on the TV.

Comment: So it's just over? I can't play it ever again?

Comment: If the studio does not make a remake, if there is no private server or if there is no clone, I'm afraid there is way for you do play the game anymore.

Comment: But when I played it there was never really a server. Also, is it possible to go through the files and remove the server connection?

Comment: Also, the link to the companies closing statements wont work

Comment: Just because you did not need to select a server does not mean there wasn't one. Think of the game like a television and the server is a channel. If the channel does not exist anymore, it doesn't matter if you manage to turn on the TV. Link is fixed

Comment: OK. This is quite sad